# Should animating individual transform properties work?

Tags: css, animation, safari, css-animations

This example works in Chrome + Firefox but not Safari v17:

```css
div {
  animation: foo 1s linear infinite;
  width: 4rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: blue;
}

@keyframes foo {
  0%, 100% {
    scale: 1;
    rotate: -20deg;
  }
  50% {
    rotate: 20deg;
    scale: 1.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I was wondering if it's a Safari bug or if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: What version of Safari and what OS? Looks OK on IOS and version 16.7.4. Check on caniuse.com

Comment: @AHaworth yeah sorry. It happens on Safari 17 iOS and macOS, and works in previous versions.

Comment: So possibly a big. What happens if you use a transform instead?

Comment: Just letting you know that viewing in Safari v17.3 (19617.2.4.11.8) on macOS Sonoma 14.3, I'm seeing the same animation as in Chrome.